# CSS: Background image not working on hover buttom

Tags: css, image, background, hover

I simply want to pass from top to bottom as a hover, but the buttom is not reacting when the mouse is on top.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/menuStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Blog</a></li>    
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {color:black; text-decoration: none; outline:none; float:left}
a:visited {color: black}
ul {list-style:none}

#menu a {display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background: url(../img/boton.png) top;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display:inline}

#menu a:hover{ color:red;
            background:url(../img/boton.png) bottom}
```

**Download the Project:**
http://gabrielmeono.com/menu.zip

Comment: i have put this into jsfiddle and it looks ok to me [jsfiddle.net/4kPuu](http://jsfiddle.net/4kPuu/) (i didn't download your project though)

Comment: It was caused by the comment I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a couple of adjustments to your CSS.

Remove the `//` comments. These do not work and break the CSS. If you need to use comments, use `/* your comment here */`.

You need to set the `background-position` as well as the `background-repeat`. By setting a -'ve background position, you move the background image up, thus bringing your image into focus. Also set `no-repeat`, just for safety.

You can read more about this technique at: http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

so this is the final CSS I came up with:

```
#menu a
{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url(../img/boton.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display:inline;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu a :active
{ 
    color:red;
    background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

Comment: I'm still not able to make it work, not even the text is changing to red... :(

Comment: @Gabriel: Probably a caching issue more than a cookie issue, but glad to see its working :)

Answer (score 1):

your css is not working because of your comment behind `display:inline;`

```
// is not a comment in css
```

instead you have to use this

```
/* this is a css comment */
```

if you change this, it should work fine

Comment: I was going to answer this but you beat me to it :-)

Comment: Thanks, I did'nt know, bad php habits I suppose.